# Facebook refusing to approve my application - Permission to mention pages

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Facebook, a multi billion dollar organisation won't fork out for some live chat agents. Instead I'm stuck in a loop asking for approval, them not reviewing my app properly and giving me a cut/paste response. They say they monitor here, so here's hoping.

Nobody but me will ever use my app. It's a PHP page that posts to our radio station's Facebook page timeline [www.facebook.com/BCnowplaying](http://www.facebook.com/BCnowplaying) every hour or so, music that's playing on [Budgie Collective](http://budgiecollective.com).

We don't want to spam, this is why the nowplaying page is separate to our normal page.

The app works. All it does is grab a token, store it and post info to the page periodically.

I asked for permission to mention pages. And it was like I divided by zero. I only want this to mention pages of the DJ that compiled the mix that's on air (which is a sanctioned mention, as they have asked for this)... so that when their mix comes on, they are notified.

When I ask for the app to be granted this ability, I get told to show how the public will log in and use the app, and to give sample user accounts. Of course I have explained all this when requesting the permissions. But I keep getting knocked back. Nobody will talk to me directly and every time I re-explain and submit, I have to wait for several days to be given an answer that has nothing to do with how my app works. It's like they aren't even reading the submission.

What can I do next?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're the only one using the application, there is no need to apply for approval. Owners of the application can already use the permission without going through the submission process.

By asking for approval you are basically telling Facebook that you want the public to use the mention feature as well.

So the solution here is to use the app as is and just change the settings to public in Settings > Status

> Do you want to make this app and all its live features available to the general public?

Switch to yes.

Comment: Thanks for the help. This is already what I have done. It's in production and in use. I need the permission to mention pages though. Without that I can only mention pages I own, and not ones I don't. It's great for testing (and it works) but my DJs manage their own pages.